# Reading files with missing value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with \t delimeter (or whitespace). However some of the entries are empty for example,

```
col1 col2
A1    A2 
      B2
```

How can I read this text in such a way that it gives me Nan in the empty entries.
Right now when I read it I will get something like this instead

```
col1 col2
A1    A2 
B2    Nan
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [reindex()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the delimeter when reading the csv:

```
In [11]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [12]: pd.read_csv(StringIO('col1\tcol2\nA1\tA2\n\tB2'), sep='\t')
Out[12]:
  col1 col2
0   A1   A2
1  NaN   B2
```

---

*Another option if it's fixed width rather than delimited is [`pd.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html).*

```
In [21]: pd.read_fwf(StringIO('col1 col2\nA1   A2\n     B2\n'))
Out[21]:
  col1 col2
0   A1   A2
1  NaN   B2
```